# My pdf conversion issue

Tags: pdf

I have downloaded a substantial amount of Wikipedia as pdf files and arranged them into a personalized library for offline reading and thinking times, and I have made a search engine that accumulates tags much the same way this site does for a question.

Trouble is, the programming IDE I made this in can't import pdf files in a human readable format, I need to be able to convert all of my pdf files into csv or txt for my search app to work.

Can anyone explain **how** the process of pdf to txt conversion works?

I was just reading this article that another person has expressed similar  [frustrations](https://sunlightfoundation.com/2009/10/28/adobe-bad-open-government/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PDF is probably **not** the right format to begin with...

Technically, "PDF text" is a collection of characters/word fragments/words with page number and coordinates. For example, *there are no spaces*, but only "room between word fragments which might be a space, or a column skip, or a table skip, or just kerning". The order of the text fragments may or may not be in reading order (...at the PDF creators discretion), because it doesn't matter for showing on screen or printing!

To mitigate that, some (but not all: all will depend on the creator) PDF files which will contain both the "text for display" and "text in reading order". Which *hopefully* is the same text as shown on screen (there is no guarantee!).

Any software which "extracts" text from PDF will have to do *lots* of interpretation. Have a look at [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11455081/podofo-extract-text-coords-from-a-pdf#20267744) for a start.

Comment: So I'm probably going to have an easier time going back and saving the whole lot as html you think? Wow its so defeating to think about how much time I've wasted obsessively compulsively downloading the pdf of every Wikipedia article I read